# Rails JSON API: Updating picture in view doesn't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, hash

New to Rails API's. I want to have an updating picture displayed in my views. The JSON data I'm pulling from can be found [here](http://www.lmsal.com/hek/her?cosec=2&cmd=search&type=column&event_type=fl,bu,&event_starttime=2017-03-01T00:00:00&event_endtime=2017-03-08T00:00:00&event_coordsys=helioprojective&x1=-1200&x2=1200&y1=-1200&y2=1200)

My Model

```
def self.get_api_info

helio_api = "http://www.lmsal.com/hek/her?cosec=2&cmd=search&type=column&event_type=fl,bu&event_starttime=2017-03-01T00:00:00&event_endtime=2017-03-08T00:00:00&event_coordsys=helioprojective&x1=-1200&x2=1200&y1=-1200&y2=1200"
request_to_helio_api = Net::HTTP.get(URI(helio_api))
JSON.parse request_to_helio_api
end
```

My Controller

```
def index
@helio_info = HelioApi.get_api_info
end
```

And my View

```
<img src="<%= @helio_info["gs_thumburl"] %>" />
```

Comment: Try `<img src="<%= @helio_info["result"]["gs_thumburl"] %>" />`

Comment: I think the error is in my model for how I handle the API. When, however, I tried this I got 'no implicit conversion of String into Integer'

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the API you're accessing is

```
{
  "result": [
    { "gs_thumburl": "some_string", ... },
    { "gs_thumburl": "some_string", ... },
    { "gs_thumburl": "some_string", ... }
  ]
}
```

So to go from `@helio_info` to `some_string` you need to grab the result array `@helio_info["result"]` and then an element in that array `@helio_info["result"][0]`, and finally grab the url `@helio_info["result"][0]["gs_thumburl"]`. Ruby said no implicit conversion of String into Integer because you tried to access an array using a string key, and it expects integer keys.

Comment: Thanks! This was a great look at what was going on, and really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insight Pavan. Here's what I ended up doing:

Model kept the same

Controller

```
def index
@helio_info = HelioApi.get_api_info['result']
puts "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*********!!!!!!!!!********!!!!!"
puts @helio_info
```

end

View

```
<% @helio_info.each do |info| %>
<% if info['gs_thumburl'] != "" %>
    <img src="<%= info['gs_thumburl']%>"/>
<%end%>
```